# How to return all integration response headers to end caller in API Gateway?

Tags: return, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, response-headers

I **want to return all headers** which API Gateway receive from integration service inside '**Integration Response**' to **end caller**.(Fiddler, postman or code)

The problem is, I am not getting those headers at client side.

While testing with **API Gateways built in test harness**, I can see all headers in upper right corner where response headers are displayed along with body and complete log.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to just return *all the headers*. For every header you want to return for every status code, you will have to add it in the Method Response for that status code. Then, you need to map these headers in the Integration Response to the headers/any other data you receive from your backend. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#mapping-response-parameters) is a list of everything that can be returned as headers in the Method Response.

Hope this helps,
Ritisha.